# Could you help me find a way how to loop through an array?

Tags: php, codeigniter, loops, foreach

I am struggling with a `foreach` function. From my database I have retrieved an array that holds information on users and the comments they have made. My goal is to loop through the array and display each user and the comments he has posted. The problem I am encountering is the duplicity of users.  I would like to know how I could write the `foreach` so that it always selects a user once, then loops through all of his comments and then does this with the next user. I hope this makes any sense. Please take a look at the code below, as it might give you a better idea of what I am trying to achieve.

**Array example**

```
| user_id | u_name | u_email | u_access | comment_id | car_id | car_comment | car_rating |
||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||
|    6    |  Jon   | j@g.com |    3     |     15     |    3   |   best car  |      5     |
|    6    |  Jon   | j@g.com |    3     |     19     |    5   |   hate it   |      1     |
|    7    |  Ben   | b@g.com |    1     |     23     |    3   |   awesome   |      5     |
|    7    |  Ben   | b@g.com |    1     |     39     |    9   |      ok     |      3     |
```

**Controller**

```
$data['data'] = $this->User-m->get_users(); //returns $this->db->get();
$this->load->view('admin_v_b', $data);
```

**View**

This is the current state of my view. As you can see it obviously results in the user being displayed as many times as many comments he has posted. I've added comments for when should each part be generated by the loop.

```
<?php foreach ($data->result() as $row): ?>
  //this div is opened only on the 1st occurrence of the user's name
  <div class="user">

    //these two fields are also generated only on the 1st occurrence of the name
    name: <?php echo $row->name ?>
    email: <?php echo $row->email ?>

    //this div and its contents is generated as many times as many comments the user has
    <div class="users_comments">
      comment: <?php echo $row->comment ?>
      rating: <?php echo $row->rating ?>
    </div>

  //the div is closed after generating all the comments
  </div>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Thank you all for reading. I appreciate your help. If you would need any additional information just ask me. Also I didn't include the `get_users()` function, because I assumed you don't need to see the actual query as that is all there is.

BTW: I have tried declaring `$last_user=""` before the `foreach` function and then adjusting it as the loop went through, but I wasn't able to get the `DIV` generating right. I am open to suggestions. :) Happy new year!

Comment: Why you don't adapt the get_users() function so you can send data to the view that is ready to parse? The things (manipulate array) you try to do in the view must be done in the model. Keep the MVC concept in mind.

Comment: so it is much easier to send a multi dimensional array to the view where the everything is already sorted. data=[user1=[],user2[],..]

Comment: Ok, but I am joining two tables `users` and `car_comments` and I can't really think of how I should parse the data to the view so that it has say array users and array user_comments and as it loops through users and loops through the comments. How would I make it so that when a user hasnt made a comment I will still get empty array inside the array, etc. The only option I can think of is call another function, say `get_users_comments(user_id)` with a script and have the results generate inside the comments div for that user, but that seems even more complicated.

Comment: Ok. Then please give me some directions. If I have table `users` with columns `ID, name, email` and table `car_comments` with columns `id, user_id, car_id, comment` How can I create an array the looks something like `[[users #1 info[all his comments]]..[users #99 info[all his comments]]]`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First I'd separate that logic out from the controller and the view. Then I'd use a separate `foreach` for the comments.

**Model**

```
<?php

function someModelMethod ($data) {

    $users = array();

    foreach ($data->result() as $row) {

        if ( ! array_key_exists($row->id, $users)) {

            $users[$row->id] = array(
                'id' => $row->id,
                'name' => $row->name,
                'email' => $row->email,
                'access' => $row->access,
                'comments' => array(),
            );
        }

        $users[$row->id]['comments'][] = array(
            'comment' => $row->comment,
            'rating' => $row->rating,
        );
    }

    return $users;
}

?>
```

**Controller**

```
<?php

$data = $this->User-m->get_users();
$users = someModelMethod($data);
$this->load->view('admin_v_b', array('users' => $users));

?>
```

**View**

```
<?php foreach ($users as $user): ?>

    <div class="user">

        name: <?php echo $user['name'] ?>
        email: <?php echo $user['email'] ?>

        <div class="users_comments">

            <?php foreach ($user['comments'] as $comment): ?>
                comment: <?php echo $comment['comment'] ?>
                rating: <?php echo $comment['rating'] ?>
            <?php endforeach; ?>

        </div>

    </div>

<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: I love you man. Thank you so so so so much. I was already trying to write it all on paper see how it goes through the array etc. But this solution is great. I was about to try wrapping the closing div into something like `if first run = true` do nothing and put it on top of the opening div, then I would generate it if the current user id was different from the last user id. But this is way better and cleaner. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You could keep an array of ids, and then wrap the code in an if statement

```
if (in_array($user[user_id], $seen)) {
  ....
  $seen[] = $user[user_id];
}
```

If you want to group comments by the user just make an array for the comments and group beforehand for exmaple

```
$comments = [];

foreach ($data as $comment) {
  $comments[$comment['user_id']][] = $comment;
}
```

Then in template

```
foreach ($comments as $set) {
  //user details
  foreach ($set as $comment) {
    //comment text
  }
}
```

Comment: Yeah that's pretty much what I did with the `$last_user`, but as I said I didn't know how to form the if statement to generate the `.user_comments` DIV inside the main div for that user.. :/

Comment: Ok I have tried implementing the other solution, but I keep getting a lot of "undefinex index" errors. Are you sure the function `->result()` doesn't need to be used?

Answer (score 0):

i got an email as a unique thing that's separate people from each other

with this Assumption you can try this:

```
<div class="user">
<?php 
$pre_userEmail = null;
foreach($data as $user){

   if( $pre_userEmail != $user['email'] ){
    echo $user['name'];
    echo $user['email'];
   }

   if( $pre_userEmail == null ) // first init
     $pre_userEmail = $user['email'];         


     echo "<div class='users_comment'>";
     echo $user['comment'];
     echo $user['raiting']
     echo "</div>";

    $pre_userEmail = $user[email];
}
?>
</div>
```

**Add**

yes, i have two situation that check $user content but they do difference. The second one that i wrote a comment for it. It's run only ones in loop and that's for first init to start my work.

the first condition is for separate people from each other.

**lets try trace my code.**

$pre_userEmail is null so print person info then init occur with first people in your array list after that print his comment and rate. At the end of the loop i change $pre_userEmail content to who i wrote his comment.

in second itration $pre_userEmail is equal with $user['email'] so he did not print his info again and second condition NOT run because it has content. so it's work fine

Comment: This doesn't look right. Why are you settings the `$pre_userEmail` to `$user['email']` twice inside the same condition? Or is there difference between `$user['email']` and `$user[email]`? Also if you first check is for `null` shouldn't it be reset back to `null` somewhere? Because now it will never reach the null state again, right?

Comment: yes, i have two situation that check $user content but they do diffrence. the second one that i wrote a comment for it. it's run only one time in loop and that's for first init to start my work.
the first condition is for separate people from each other.